# What is the error in this SQL, how to fix it?

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I'm a newbie who can't understand the error in this mysql syntax. Can anyone help?

```
 mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'tbl_issue'
        -> (
        -> 'id' INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        -> 'name' varchar(256) NOT NULL,
        -> 'description' varchar(2000),
        -> 'project_id' INTEGER,
        -> 'type_id' INTEGER,
        -> 'status_id' INTEGER,
        -> 'owner_id' INTEGER,
        -> 'requester_id' INTEGER,
        -> 'create_time' DATETIME,
        -> 'create_user_id' INTEGER,
        -> 'update_time' DATETIME,
        -> 'update_user_id' INTEGER
        -> ) ENGINE = InnoDB
        -> ;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''tbl_issue'
>       (
>       'id' INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
>       'name' varchar(2' at line 1
>       mysql> CREATE TABLE 'tbl_issue'
>           -> (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backticks should be used for table and field names rather than single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the quotes from all identifiers.